# Can't access the calendars in office365 groups

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I got Unauthorized when calling to get Calendar in the Microsoft graph API, I use this verification to retrieve an access token.

I think the problem is that when I want to retrieve the Get HTTP request on Calendar the access token isn't created with credentials which result in the Unauthorized call. How can I change my code to be able to send Credentials with it and get a better Token with more privileges?

In the Azure portal, I granted all permissions to see whether that the application permissions weren't set correctly.

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(_azureAd_ClientId, _azureAd_SecretKey);

string tokenResult;

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
try
{
    authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_azureAd_GraphResource, clientCred);
    var user = authenticationResult.UserInfo;
    string_token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    tokenResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authenticationResult);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
}
```

Comment: Is the value of `_azureAd_GraphResource` `https://graph.microsoft.com`?

Comment: Yes, but with a end slash  "https://graph.microsoft.com/"

Comment: Yeah that is fine. Have you added app permissions? Since you are using client credentials, delegated permissions don't apply here. Also, note you must grant those permissions e.g. with the Grant permissions button in the portal.

Comment: Yeah i have done that, everything works fine when i try it on postman but not in my code

Comment: Then you need to find out what you are doing differently, because it should work the same way if all the parameters are same.

Comment: In postman you have redirectUrl and you have to log in that's the difference. I know that there exist others that has this problem. Have you tried retrieving a calendar from a user this way? 
I can access all but calendar and mail, i can get the user and groups and other things but not the calendar.

Comment: After adding the permissions, did you re-consent the app? Admin Consent will only consent to the scopes that were checked off. If you add/remove scopes then Admin Consent needs to be re-executed.

Comment: @Marc I granted the permission and removed and renewed the Token. How do I re-consent the app?

Comment: Are you yourself an admin on the tenant?

Comment: Yes, I'm a Global admin

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the comments it seems that you may need to trigger a new consent prompt in order to grant the application the permissions you have re-configured. If this is a V1 app, you can do so by adding prompt=admin_consent to the end of your request. If this is a V2 app, you will want to use the /adminconsent endpoint. More info on that is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint).

There is also some more documentation on admin consent in general [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent).